# Dividing Unit Square in to 7 equal areas

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-construction

Is it possible to divide say a UNIT Square in to seven equal areas. Two trivial solutions are dividing using $6$ Horizontal(Vertical) lines as shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to divide it using Straight lines which are Oblique?

Comment: By "equal areas" do you mean "equal surface but possibly different shape"? Or must the shapes be also equal?

Comment: shapes need not be equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this.

Here is one way.  Using the points in your diagram (but not your horizontal lines),  calling the leftmost column of points $a_0, a_1, ...,a_7$ (bottom to top) and the rightmost column $b_0, b_1,...,b_7$ (also bottom to top).  Then draw line segments joining

$a_0$ to $b_2$;

$a_1$ to $b_3$;

$a_2$ to $b_4$;

$a_3$ to $b_5$;

$a_4$ to $b_6$;

$a_5$ to $b_7$.